# What does "get" mean in this sentence "someone from talent acquisition will come get you"?

Tags: meaning

See this conversation:

> Ben: I'm Ben whittaker. I received an e-mail about an interview for
>   the senior intern program.
>
> Lady: Hey, Ben. How's it going?
>
> Ben: It's going good, real good. Thank you.
>
> Lady: Excellent. Take a seat around the corner, and someone from
>   talent acquisition will come **get** you.
>
> Ben: Thank you. "Talent acquisition"?

In the dictionary

> [Get](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/get): CATCH SOMEBODY [transitive] to catch someone
>
> The police got him in the end.

But, **[catch](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/catch)** in the dictionary refers to **negative events** such as robberies or something like that

> 2 FIND/STOP SOMEBODY [transitive]
>
> a) to stop someone after you have been chasing them and not let them
>   get away
>
> ‘You can’t catch me!’ she yelled, running away.
>
> b) to find a criminal or enemy and stop them from escaping SYN capture
>
> State police have launched a massive operation to catch the murderer.
>
> If you go back to the city, you’re bound to get caught.

But the above interview context has nothing to do with robberies

What does "**get**" mean in this sentence "someone from talent acquisition will come **get** you"?

Answer (score 2):

'Get' in this context means to come over to where you are and escort you somewhere.

This is the third definition in the dictionary you link to, saying

> [transitive] to bring someone or something back from somewhere

In this case, the person being sent to 'get' you is bringing you back to reception, or wherever else they might take you.